# Passing multiple variables to javascript onclick in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am attempting to pass an id and a code though a javascript method onclick in vb.net. I am getting the error 'example string' is not defined. All the other variable will pass though without problem. Maybe I have the syntax wrong. I'm not sure.

```
For Each skillDetail As StationEmployeSkill In empDetail.EmployeeSkills
    If skillDetail.IsExpired And GlobalsFSiA.HighlightSkillsAfterExpiring > -1 Then
        td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='EndSkill(" & empDetail.EmployeeId & "," & skillDetail.SkillCode & ");'><font color=""red"">" & skillDetail.SkillCode & "&nbsp;</font></a>"
    ElseIf skillDetail.ExpiresSoon And GlobalsFSiA.HighlightSkillsBeforeExpiring > -1 Then
        td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='EndSkill(" & empDetail.EmployeeId & "," & skillDetail.SkillCode & ");'><font color=""blue"">" & skillDetail.SkillCode & "&nbsp;</font></a>"
    ElseIf skillDetail.ForeColor <> "" Then
        td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='EndSkill(" & empDetail.EmployeeId & "," & skillDetail.SkillCode & ");'><font color=""" & skillDetail.ForeColor & """>" & skillDetail.SkillCode & "&nbsp;</a>"
    Else
        td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='EndSkill(" & empDetail.EmployeeId & "," & skillDetail.SkillCode & ");'><font color=""black"">" & skillDetail.SkillCode & "&nbsp;</font></a>"
    End If

Next
td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='AddSkill(" & empDetail.EmployeeId & ");'><font color=""green"">+&nbsp;</font></a>"
tr.Cells.Add(td)
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic quotes issue, You should pass `empDetail.EmployeeId` and `skillDetail.SkillCode` with in quotes to be treated as string parameter. Otherwise they will be treated as *variables* which obviously you have not defined thus will get the error.

Here I have esacped quotes

```
td.Text += "<a href='#' onclick='EndSkill(""" & empDetail.EmployeeId & """,""" & skillDetail.SkillCode & """);'>"
```

Escape double-quotes in VB is by doubling the double-quotes: